# Getting XML element from nested child values via XPath

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<PACKAGES>
    <PACKAGE>
        <SHORT-NAME>Element1</SHORT-NAME>
        <PACKAGES>
            <PACKAGE>
                <SHORT-NAME>Element2</SHORT-NAME>
                <ELEMENTS>
                    <MODULE>
                        <SHORT-NAME>Element3</SHORT-NAME>
                        <DESC>
                        </DESC>
                        <CATEGORY>Item</CATEGORY>
                    </MODULE>
                </ELEMENTS>
            </PACKAGE>
        </PACKAGES>
    </PACKAGE>
</PACKAGES>
```

I would like the ability to build an XPath query to the MODULE element with the SHORT-NAME of "Element3", based on the SHORT-NAMES of "Element3"'s parents...so something like this:

```
//SHORT-NAME='Element1'.//SHORT-NAME='Element2'.//SHORT-NAME='Element3'
```

I've tried the above query, but it doesn't seem to work, not a valid query. I've also tried this:

```
//*[text()='Element1']//*[text()='Element2'] etc...
```

but again, this doesn't seem to be a valid query.

I'd like this to be scale-able such that the specific query could be any path, but the path is always based on the text value of SHORT-NAME.

So something like:

```
/Element1/SubElement2/SubSubElement3/SubSubSubElement4
```

could also be queried for.

An important note: For the above query, I ONLY want Element3 IF it is a child of Element2, who is a child of Element1. IF Element3 exists elsewhere in the document, I do NOT want that node.

I'm hoping this is possible I'm just not building the right query, but I'm at a loss for how to even search for this topic to try to find the answer.

**EDIT:** The answer provided below by Andersson almost 100% works for my use-case. The issue is highlighted below:

If I still need to query /Element1/Element2/Element3 but my XML looks like below:

```
<PACKAGES>
    <PACKAGE>
        <SHORT-NAME>Element1</SHORT-NAME>
        <PACKAGES>
            <PACKAGE>
                <SHORT-NAME>Element2</SHORT-NAME>
                <ELEMENTS>
                    <PACKAGE>
                    <SHORT-NAME>RandomElement</SHORT-NAME>
                        <MODULE>
                            <SHORT-NAME>Element3</SHORT-NAME>
                            <DESC>
                            </DESC>
                            <CATEGORY>Item</CATEGORY>
                        </MODULE>
                    </PACKAGE>
                </ELEMENTS>
            </PACKAGE>
        </PACKAGES>
    </PACKAGE>
</PACKAGES>
```

Element3 is still returned, however Element3's parent is not Element2. This makes thing more complicated and I suspect I will need to create a function that systematically goes through a search for the next child SHORT-NAME and to check if the for query is satisfied. Unless the XPath query could be modified in such a way to satisfy the above use-case.

Comment: in the example there is no `module` item on other levels. `//module`will  find it

Comment: For sure that's a good point. I should have elaborated however that each node I want to query for might actually be different, not specifically MODULE each time. I will only know the path of the element (/Element1/Element2/Element3) and not the specific type when the query is performed.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by *based on the SHORT-NAMES of "Element3"'s parents*? Do you want to match node with value `"Element3"` which is descendant of node with value `"Element2"` which is descendant of node `"Element1"`?

Comment: Yes exactly. I ONLY want Element3 which is a child of Element2 which is a child of Element1 specifically. If Element3 exist elsewhere in the document I do not want that one. I'll add this to the post as I think this is a critical point I missed.

Comment: i think you can't do that with single query when you don't know level and value is concatination of string and integer. Find `//*[SHORT-NAME='Element1']` and then find `.//*[SHORT-NAME='Element2']` etc. while xpath will return items

Comment: Regarding **EDIT**: Are you saying that you want to select the `MODULE` element with a `SHORT-NAME` of `Element3` in the first XML document but nothing in the second XML document?

Comment: Resolution of ambiguity is going on quite a while here, and your new EDIT is making matters more complicated.   Why don't you start a new question and make it clear exactly what you want selected in which XML documents and what you do not want selected in each case?

Comment: Fair point, I will create a new question soon.

Comment: Posted a related question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053432/get-xml-node-based-on-heritage-of-element-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='Element3']
```

will select all elements, regardless of their names, which have a `SHORT-NAME` child with a string value of `Element3`.

If you wish to specify the target element's heritage, extend the pattern upward as many levels as necessary:

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='Element1']//*[SHORT-NAME='Element2']//*[SHORT-NAME='Element3']
```

Comment: Thanks, @Andersson!

Comment: Wow, yup this worked! I was on the right path (no pun intended) just slight syntax error!

Comment: @bryken what's about `/Element1/SubElement2/SubSubElement3/SubSubSubElement4`  ?

Comment: Mainly I was trying to say that the solution should be scale-able so that I could make requests like that. The above answer does allow this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to come back to this answer. There is a slight problem with this solution...it turns out that this solution does not guarantee that Element2 is the first occurence SHORT-NAME under Element1, or that Element3 is the first occurence SHORT-NAME under Element2. I did a query like above, except that the actual path was something like /Element1/Element2/RandomElement/Element3, which isn't a correct path for what I need. Anyway to guarantee that the first occurrence of a SHORT-NAME under its parent is what is specified in the query?

Comment: `//` is for self or descendent.   `/` is for immediate child.

Comment: I edited the original question to provide a more in-depth explanation of the issue. I don't think / will work because I'm not looking for the next child but rather the next child occurrence of SHORT-NAME.