# Get XML node based on heritage of element values

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

```
<XXX>
    <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT1</SHORT-NAME>
    <YYY>
        <ZZZ>
            <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT2</SHORT-NAME>
            <AAA>
                <BBB>
                    <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT3</SHORT-NAME>
                    <CCC></CCC>
                    <DDD></DDD>
                    <EEE></EEE>
                    <FFF>
                        <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT4</SHORT-NAME>
                    </FFF>
                    <GGG>
                        <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT6</SHORT-NAME>
                    </GGG>
                </BBB>
                <HHH>
                    <SHORT-NAME>ELEMENT5</SHORT-NAME>
                </HHH>
            </AAA>
        </ZZZ>
    </YYY>
</XXX>
```

The idea is that the ELEMENT(s) each represent a package or container and each subelement represents a subelement or package of it's parent. The packages are named based on their SHORT-NAME. There can be an arbitrary number of elements inbetween an element and it's child packages. This XML file is provided to me and I have no input in changing it as this layout is well defined.

The way that "others" address various elements within the above XML is based on their location relative to it's parents and addressed by its SHORT-NAME. So for instance, in the above example `/ELEMENT1/ELEMENT2/ELEMENT3/ELEMENT4` is a valid way to address the `<FFF>` element based on it's SHORT-NAME. On the flip side, something like `/ELEMENT1/ELEMENT2/ELEMENT4` would NOT be a valid way to address ELEMENT4 because ELEMENT4 is technically a "child" of ELEMENT3.

So I had posted a question yesterday about how to use XPath to retrieve certain elements based on their SHORT-NAMEs and the solution that was proposed was like this:

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT1']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT2']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT3']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT4']
```

This would work in the above example, however the isse with this is that if instead I used an XPath like this:

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT1']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT2']//[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT4']
```

It would still retrieve ELEMENT4, and **in reality if someone doesn't know the exact path/heiarchy of the element they need, they should not be able to retrieve it. This is a key point.**

My hope is that this could be solved with a XPath query.

Comment: Do you mean that all nodes with `SHORT-NAME` child **must** be mentioned in XPath?

Comment: In the above example, ELEMENT4 and ELEMENT6 would be considered "siblings" and their "parent" is ELEMENT3. So to address ELEMENT4 or ELEMENT6 you would need /ELEMENT1/ELEMENT2/ELEMENT3/ELEMENT4 or /ELEMENT1/ELEMENT2/ELEMENT3/ELEMENT6. ONLY those paths can address those nodes.

Comment: It seems he was able to get the information needed out of my answer as his proposed solution below works. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use below:

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT1']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT2']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT3']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT4' and count(./ancestor-or-self::*[./SHORT-NAME])=4]
```

The idea is to specify manually the number of nodes mentioned in your path (in provided example it is `"4"`). Expression will return you desired node only if all ancestors that have `SHORT-NAME` child were mentioned in path, so

```
//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT1']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT2']//*[SHORT-NAME='ELEMENT4' and count(./ancestor-or-self::*[./SHORT-NAME])=3]
```

should not return you required node